# cocoa / objective c : How to know which control is under the cursor?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am making an application which will detect global mouse events and log the action performed.

For example : If i click on close/minimize button on finder(or any other app like firefox,safari etc) then the app should be able to detect this. Till now i could find the window name under the cursor when click is made. So i can capture mouse click events. But i am not able to find on how to detect exact which button/control was clicked on that window.

I am using `NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseDownMask| NSRightMouseDownMask ) handler:^(NSEvent *event){ }` for capturing mouse events.

So Is there a way i could know which button/control was clicked? Or in case a folder icon is clicked on finder then is there a way to know that selected folder name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple. Check UIElementInspector example in dev.apple.com mac library. Following is the link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html